# Prevent window shake from minimizing all other windows

Tags: windows-7, aero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable Aero Shake in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/12156/how-do-i-disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7)

In Windows 7, if you grab a window and shake it back and forth, there is a shortcut to minimize all the windows.

I keep doing this by accident so I would like to disable this feature.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the "search programs and files" box type

> gpedit.msc

right click on the search result and run as administrator

Go to User Configuration > administrative templates > desktop

In there at the bottom(-ish) you will see "Turn off aero shake window minimizing mouse gesture", double click it and make your selection in the window that opens

Comment: +1 easier for beginners :)

Comment: I had to lock and unlock my computer to get it to take effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It requires you to edit the registry.  [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7/) is an article on how to do it.

Comment: I tried this approach in Windows 8 and found that it had no effect.