# (Win7) Disable auto minimize all windows when dragging one

Tags: windows-7, aero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable Aero Shake in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/12156/how-do-i-disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7)

There's this feature in Windows 7 that makes all windows minimize when you drag one around. I am not sure what triggers it, as it feels like it just happens from time to time. Is there any way to disable this feature all together? I am not talking about the feature that makes all windows transparent when you hover over one of the thumbs in the menu bar, I am talking about actually minimizing everything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the Window Shake.  If you move a window side to side, it minimizes all the other Windows.

To disable: [From How-To Geek.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7/)

> Disable Aero Shake Manual Registry Hack
>
> Open up regedit.exe through the start menu search or run box, and then
>   navigate down to the following key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
>
> Once you are there, right-click on the Windows key and create a new
>   key called Explorer.
>
> Now right-click on the right-hand side, create a new 32-bit DWORD with
>   the following settings:
>
> Name: NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts Value: 1
>
> Once you’ve created this, you should log off and back on for the
>   change to take effect.

Comment: Thank you very much. This feature has annoyed me ever since I started using Win7, so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/hnupg/til_that_you_can_shake_a_window_in_windows_7_and/: Side note,  the inventor of the feature was on reddit. He tells the story about how originally they had fought to keep the feature by showing alpha tester laughing when they first discovered the feature.  In a sense, I'm glad they kept it in as it makes for a good feature to keep my little cousins busy.

Comment: that's a terrible reason to leave in a feature with a completely opaque method of disabling it. it's a frustrating "feature" that only seems to trigger when you're at work combing through windows and trying to arrange all of the information you need and then BAM! all your windows are gone and no amount of shaking seems to trigger the reverse action. "but people LAUGHED!" :|

Comment: Thank you for resolution of this terrible feature, which makes crazy all the people in our office...

Comment: @mendota: If you take the same window and shake it again, it will undo the minimize all action.