# When I wave with a window, all other windows minimize to the taskbar, why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, aero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable Aero Shake in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/12156/how-do-i-disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7)

Sometimes, and I really don't know how to do it, when I grab an application in the window-bar and drag it around, as if I'm waving, then all other windows are minimized to the taskbar.

I have three questions:

- how do I do this?
- what's this feature called in Windows 7
- how can I disable this Windows 7 feature?

I know I can undo it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Mine doesn't seem to do it anyways? W7 Pro :o

Comment: How to disable it was [asked and answered on SuperUser back in 2009](http://superuser.com/questions/12156/).

Comment: @JdeBP - Indeed it is.  Voting to close.  (Why didn't you?)

Comment: Because three minus one is not zero.

Comment: Many people might not know that this feature is called “Aero Shake”—especially as the days when Aero was the new and popular thing to talk about have become history. I think this question is better than the one it is marked as a duplicate simply because it describes the issue in a way that one who doesn’t know the feature’s name can actually find it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This feature is called [Shake](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/shake).  Just wiggle a window vigorously to minimize all other windows. You can also just release the click on the window, then click again and waggle to undo this.

Disabling Shake entirely requires a registry edit:

1. Browse to the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
   ```

   (the Explorer key may not be there by default, just create it)
2. Make a 32-bit DWORD called "NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts".
3. Set the value to 1.

Comment: I'd just add that personally I've done this by accident maybe once ever, so I don't see a need to disable it.  It can come in handy.

Comment: Apparently I have a shaky hand sometimes. When I try it on purpose, I don't manage to do it. But by accident, it happens, say, once a week or so, much to my surprise and annoyance (I like my messy overlaid windows on my big screens).

Comment: In **Windows 10** you need to create a 32-bit DWORD value called `DisallowShaking` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and set it to `1`

Comment: So far I've been able to wiggle with my mouse, but I'm having trouble with the waggle. Is it all in the wrist, or do I need a touchscreen?

Comment: @ntv1000 's comment applies to Windows 7 also.

Comment: This: click again and waggle to undo this, is worth one thousand upvotes!

Comment: @ntv1000 can you please make an actual response so we can all upvote it? You're the real MVP here. :)

Answer (score 9):

It most certainly is a 'feature' of Windows 7 and it's called 'Aero Shake', more details can be found here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/shake

And what you are describing is exactly how it works. Grab the title bar of any window, give it a shake and everything else drops to the task bar.

To disable Shake you'll need to use either the Group Policy editor or do some registry tweaking as outlined here:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-aero-shake-in-windows-7/

Comment: Didn't realize you could do this in gpedit, that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks, you both answered this thoroughly and it's good to know that GP editor can do this.

Comment: If you could quote or place the instructions [directly in your answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), that’d improve the quality of this answer.