# How to disable the "wiggling" feature in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

If you have several open windows, and you grab one of them and wiggle it around (instead of slowly moving the window). All other windows will be minimized.

How is that "wiggling" feature actually called and how can I disable it?

Comment: **See Also** [How do I disable Aero Shake in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/12156/180163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the **Aero Shake** gesture, use the Local Group Policy Editor (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>; `gpedit.msc`) to *enable* the group policy **Turn off Aero Shake window minimizing mouse gesture**.
[image: Windows Shake Group Policy]

It's located in **User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop**.

Comment: Note: Home versions of Windows do not have gpedit.

Comment: Setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\NoWindowMinimizingShortcuts` to `1` in `regedit` might do the trick.