# editing local group policies with windows registry

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, local

I am trying to edit the local group policy by using windows registry. I noticed something odd : changing the register value does not affect the local group policy editor.

Example : when I navigate in the registry Editor to HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions and that I set AllowAdministratorInstall to 0 instead of 1, it does not change anything in the local group policy editor and "Allow administrators to override Device Installation Restriction Policies" is still marked as "Enabled".

It does not work either if I restart the machine.
I am working on Windows 10 64bits.

Does anyone have an explanation for this ?

Comment: Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional?  Once you changed the registry key, you logged out of the user, and logged back into it?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional. Once I changed the registry key, I restart the machine.

Comment: GPO are mirrored to registry, but not the other way. 
See https://superuser.com/q/1192405/471143